# Group by list of string / list of enum

Tags: angular, typescript, group-by

I have list of object like this:

```
enum TypeOfMeal {
  Breakfast,
  Dinner,
  Supper
}

interface Dish {
  name: string,
  category: TypeOfMeal[],
}

const dishes: Dish[] = [
  {
    name: 'Burger',
    category: [TypeOfMeal.Breakfast, TypeOfMeal.Dinner]
  },
  {
    name: 'Chips',
    category: [TypeOfMeal.Supper]
  },
  {
    name: 'Cereal with milk',
    category: [TypeOfMeal.Breakfast]
  }
];
```

I want groupped my `dishes` by `category`, so i want this output:

```
{
  'Breakfast': [
    {
      name: 'Burger',
      category: ['Breakfast', 'Dinner']
    },
    {
      name: 'Cereal with milk',
      category: ['Breakfast']
    }
  ],
  'Dinner': [
    {
      name: 'Burger',
      category: ['Breakfast', 'Dinner']
    },
  ],
  'Supper': [
    {
      name: 'Chips',
      category: ['Supper']
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```js
function groupBy<T>(
  getKeys: (item: T) => (string | number | symbol)[],
  items: T[]
): Record<string | number | symbol, T[]> {
  const result: Record<string | number | symbol, T[]> = {};

  for (const item of items) {
    for (const key of getKeys(item)) {
      if (!result[key]) {
        result[key] = [];
      }

      result[key].push(item);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

groupBy((dish) => dish.category, dishes);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer

StackOverflow isn't meant to provide freelance programming, it's more about teaching and learning :)

---

### What you need

Therefore, here's the tools you need:

1. [Documentation for `Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
2. [Documentation for Spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
   (more specifically, the sections "Spread in array literals" and "Spread in object literals")
3. [Documentation for the Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
   (not really necessary, but it's always good to know)

---

### What you want

And just in case, here's the answer you want:

```js
dishes.reduce(
  (res, dish) => dish.category.reduce((acc, meal) => ({ ...acc, [TypeOfMeal[meal]]: [...(acc[TypeOfMeal[meal]] ?? []), dish] }), res),
  {} as { [key: string]: Dish[] },
)
```

---

I reckon you may actually be better off keeping the keys of your resulting set as `TypeOfMeal` rather than the `string` representation of the `enum`.
Just have them "translate" when you need to present them!

```js
dishes.reduce(
  (res, dish) => dish.category.reduce((acc, meal) => ({ ...acc, [meal]: [...(acc[meal] ?? []), dish] }), res),
  {} as { [key in TypeOfMeal]: Dish[] },
)
```